# Why zmq(python) is dropping messages when burst sending?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm testing zmq performance by burst sending 100000 messages. The client count the received messages and measure the time used.
On my local machine, the client received every message, but on VPS ( I tried several different model), some of the messages were dropped.
Not sure something wrong with VPS or something wrong with zmq.

Sender:

```
import zmq 
import random
import cbor
import time

context = zmq.Context()  
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)  
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:27700")
time.sleep(2)

socket.send_multipart([b'test.latency', b'start'])
for i in range(100000):
    s = str(random.random())
    socket.send_multipart([b'test.latency', s.encode()])
socket.send_multipart([b'test.latency', b'end'])
```

Receiver:

```
import datetime
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()  
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)  
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:27700")  
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'test.latency'.encode())

s = None
count = 0
while True:
    try:
        topic, msg = socket.recv_multipart()
        count += 1
        if msg == b'start': s = datetime.datetime.now()
        if msg == b'end': break
    except Exception: pass

print(count) # should be 100002
print((datetime.datetime.now() - s).total_seconds())
```

The correct count printed by the receiver should be 100002 (including the start and end).

---

[UPDATE]:

This issue can be solved by setting the HWM to 0 explicitly.

Add `socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDHWM, 0)` and `socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVHWM, 0)` in the sender and receiver respectively.

But strange, by the doc the HWM is 0 by default. [ZMQ_HWM](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-setsockopt#toc3)

Comment: How many are missing. Is there a pattern? It might be helpful to send a sequence as payload instead of random values to see that.

Comment: No, there is no pattern, seems to be totally random.

Comment: on average, how many go missing?  5? 50? 5000?

Comment: are both tests run "locally" as it were?  i.e. both sender and receiver are on the same machine, in the first case both on your local machine, and in the second case both on your VPS?

Comment: check both environments to see what the [high water mark](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-setsockopt#toc3) is set to.  If there's any additional latency on the VPS, and the HWM is set, it may be reached in that context and start dropping messages, intentionally.

Comment: On average, about 10% drop. Yes, both tests run "locally". I didn't set HWM in the code, which means "no limit" by the doc. But what's strange, after I setting the SNDHWM and RCVHWM to 0 explicitly, in the sender and receiver respectively, it works perfectly  :-)